# Girl that can take shortcut through space by taking a 1/2 turn as she steps up

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, parallel-universe

This was a pre-1970s YA book.

I cannot recall much about the plot, but I was impressed by her entering an alternate universe where three parallel lines intersected to form a right angle. I think her father was also able to travel like this, but her mother didn't approve.  She develops a friendship with a boy, who she takes into this alternate universe.  I think there is a problem with the dad – sick or imprisoned or ostracized.

Comment: Parallel Lines: Lines in a plane which do not meet; that is, two lines in a plane that do not intersect or touch at any point are said to be parallel. So is this 3 lines from 3 parallel universes that intersect? Perhaps Euclidean geometry rings a bell in this story?

Comment: That is exactly why this impressed me as a kid.  I kept trying to visualize it.  In the alternate universe the parallel lines could intersect.  She was afraid to bring the boy into the universe because he would see things that might shock him.

Comment: I'm thinking of The Universe Between by Alan E.Nourse, but it was a woman and her son who could do this. In the alternate universe you could 'smell' sounds and 'hear' colours.

Comment: Post that as an answer, sueelleker? 
"Three perfectly parallel lines which met each other at ninety-degree angles to form a perfect square with seven triangular sides..."- The Universe Between

Comment: Sueelleker and Frock, thanks. Might be "The Universe", but I thought there was more of the young girl, maybe that's why I do not remember more of the plot.  And Thresholders sounds familiar.  Also the exchange of material, but I thought that was a different book.  Was the young Gail only at the very beginning of the book?  Even if this isn't it, I am ordering that book.  Based on the quote from Frock, I'd say this is it though.

Comment: Bought The Universe Between and read first section.  Not the book I was thinking of.  In the one I wanted, it wasn't an experiment.  Travel between universes was easy for her.  She would use it as a short cut like when she was late for school.  I also think the girl was younger, maybe early teens.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a bit like *A Wrinkle In Time* by Madeleine L'Engle:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time

Comment: it sounds like a wrinkle in time to me as well, the dad is trapped , and the girl goes and saves him, and brings her friend/brother Charles Wallace with. I believe that dad does die at the end, or was sick, but he was defiantly trapped which is why the daughter goes to save him.

Comment: It's not Wrinkle in Time.