# Looking for a novel: young man takes shortcuts through another dimension

Tags: story-identification, novel

This is a novel I read in the 60s. I thought it was by Nourse but it's not. The story was about a young man who used his mind to turn a corner into another dimension that allowed him to take short cuts, allowing him to go from point A to point B without hitting the points between.

Comment: Please add more detail to your description. Anything you can remember. How does it differ from Nourse's *The Universe Between*?

Comment: If it's not Nourse, possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80007/girl-that-can-take-shortcut-through-space-by-taking-a-1-2-turn-as-she-steps-up ?

Answer (score 7):

It was Nourse - it's *The Universe Between*. From [an Amazon review](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Universe-Between-Alan-Edward-Nourse/dp/0441854567):

> Scientists inadvertently open a doorway into a parallel universe - one appearing so strange as to drive observers insane. All except one; a young woman who learns to enter the other world at will - as later does her son. This is story of his gradually dawning understanding of what the "Threshold" really is - and it's potential as mankind's route to the stars - but there is a problem... the inhabitants of the other universe.